# How to change the timeout of GRUB Boot loader screen in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: 14.04, grub2, timeout

I use Ubuntu 14.10 virtual machine in headless mode and access it using ssh. But many a times it gets stuck on GRUB boot loader screen and I have to log in to the VM in graphical mode and restart in headless mode. But after some time this problem resurfaces, mainly when VM is not shutdown properly.

So I would like to set the timeout of the boot loader screen to a very low value for the cases when VM is not closed properly.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the following link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/121008/server-boots-to-grub-prompt-after-reboot 
I am not posting this as an answer since the GRUB-configuration in 14.10 might be different, but in general this is the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)

Answer (score 4):

You can read the full documentation [here](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Konfiguration). In general it is two steps:

1. Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` as root (or with `sudo`) and set the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` variable to whatever you want.
2. Make the changes visible by calling `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Since Ammy6Teen mentions that this mainly happens when the VM is not properly shutdown you might also want to mention `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT= ` in your answer. This variable sets the timeout when there was an error in the last session (e.g. power failure).