# Bootloader Failure

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I was updating my Ubuntu and it got stuck on installing for x86/efi and stopped responding. So I forced restart then all of what I get is a black grub page. I had such problem before and someone assisted me with set of commands on how to fix it. I don't have a USB image or any other PC, so I'll be glad if Simone could assist me on how to fix it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByyPouf1Q_9kenp1NDd6OGlKdWc/view?usp=docslist_api

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server boots to grub prompt after reboot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121008/server-boots-to-grub-prompt-after-reboot)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
ls
set prefix=(hdX,Y)/boot/grub
set root=(hdX,Y)
set
ls /boot
insmod /boot/grub/linux.mod
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdXY ro
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

All credit goes to @gkanwar in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/181733/how-can-i-restore-grub-without-a-live-cd)

PS in case you need some "official" guidelines on [GRUB2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)

Comment: Ls /boot returned nothing. While root was mounted correctly

Comment: Set prefix for boot shows boot folder empty, while set root worked and I accessed it's contents